# Making imported column to a Lookup Value

Tags: list, lookup-column, import

I did a Excel import to a SharePoint list, there are 3-4 columns that are lookup values. Is there a way to make those columns lookup values again? I tried to edit the column but only options seem to be single text, Single line of text ,Multiple lines of text, Choice (menu to choose from), Number (1, 1.0, 100). I don't see a lookup value field.

I tried to created separate columns and make those lookups, but the current data that I imported is not going to be in those columns since it is a separate column, so I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

That is the limitation with importing a spreadsheet.

You could make them choice columns or lookup columns to other Sharepoint lists you'd need to create. Once created, you'd then need to update the data, datasheet view could help speed that up, or you could then try deleting all the content and pasting the Excel data into datasheet view.

Comment: there is about 10000 records thats why i did the import, but how would i make the imported column a lookup if the option is not allowed? Also making it a choice column what would that do?

Comment: a choice field, you'd need to supply all the values into the options area. to create lookup fields, you need to create separate lists, populate the data, then create fields that lookup to that list

Comment: so would what i have to do with the columns that were suppose to be lookups but when i did the import they are not

Comment: you can do one of these with them: 1) do nothing with them 2) switch them to a choice column and populate the options with your lookup values 3) create new lists to hold your data and then create new lookup columns pointing to those lists.